# PostgreSQL update query takes long time to execute

Tags: postgresql, optimization, sql-update

I have an update query that is to update approximately 30,000 records out of 1 million records in the table. But the execution goes on and on without giving any response. Can someone guide as how can I optimize the query for faster execution. 
The query is mentioned below:

```
UPDATE ccdb.consumer_index_details ci
SET dtr_id = dsm.survey_dtr_code, fdr_id = SUBSTRING(dsm.survey_dtr_code,1,7),ss_id = SUBSTRING(dsm.survey_dtr_code,1,5), r_apdrp_town_flag = 1
FROM ccdb.dtr_stg ds, ccdb.dtr_survey_map dsm, ccdb.consumers c
WHERE ds.dtr_name = dsm.display_name
AND ci.dtr_id = ds.dtr_code
AND dsm.dtr_code = ds.dtr_code
AND ds.sec_code  = '6533'
AND ci.cin = c.cin
AND c.org_unit_id = 6533
AND ci.dtr_id IN (SELECT dtr_code FROM ccdb.dtr_survey_map);
```

The code is for PostgreSQL 9.2.

**UPDATE: Added the Query Plan**

```
"Update on consumer_index_details ci  (cost=267.79..227219.89 rows=27759 width=628)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=267.79..227219.89 rows=27759 width=628)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=267.79..65652.98 rows=1 width=622)"
"              Join Filter: ((dsm.dtr_code)::text = (dtr_survey_map.dtr_code)::text)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=267.79..65625.25 rows=1 width=652)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((ci.dtr_id)::text = (dsm.dtr_code)::text)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on consumer_index_details ci  (cost=0.00..57920.36 rows=1982436 width=605)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=267.78..267.78 rows=1 width=47)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=243.98..267.78 rows=1 width=47)"
"                                Hash Cond: (((dsm.display_name)::text = (ds.dtr_name)::text) AND ((dsm.dtr_code)::text = (ds.dtr_code)::text))"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on dtr_survey_map dsm  (cost=0.00..17.88 rows=788 width=41)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=241.41..241.41 rows=171 width=31)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on dtr_stg ds  (cost=0.00..241.41 rows=171 width=31)"
"                                            Filter: ((sec_code)::text = '6533'::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on dtr_survey_map  (cost=0.00..17.88 rows=788 width=18)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on consumers c  (cost=0.00..161011.73 rows=27759 width=6)"
"              Filter: (org_unit_id = 6533)"
```

Comment: You have to give us the result of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Houari: Please find the question updated with the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: `AND c.org_unit_id = 6533` : this is the only reference to the consumers table. (would you **please** use the join syntax ?)

Comment: you want me to use the JOIN syntax where and for which tables?? Can I use the join statement to JOIN the table which I am updating??

Comment: `FROM ccdb.dtr_stg ds JOIN ccdb.dtr_survey_map dsm ON ... JOIN ccdb.consumers c ON ...`. And you will see that the `c` alias will not be related to any other RTE . (and is not used in the SELECT list either ) So the result will effectively be a (partial) Carthesian product. UPDATE: now I see the `AND ci.cin = c.cin` clause. sorry!

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT count(dtr_code) FROM ccdb.dtr_survey_map` ?

Comment: Also, how big is `dtr_survey_map` (bytes): `select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('dtr_survey_map'));` . It's being sequentially scanned inside two nested loops so unless it's very small, that's going to hurt.

Comment: SELECT count(dtr_code) FROM ccdb.dtr_survey_map = 788

select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('dtr_survey_map')) = 80kB

Comment: Your query text has a join on the `cin` column, but that join/filter is not reflected anywhere in our query plan.  Are you sure the plan and the query belong to each other?

Comment: yeah jjanes... the query and the plan do belong to each other.